# Selecionar Fornecedores por Nome Fantasia

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de PRODUTO e nele há um relacionamento com a tabela FORNECEDOR, como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual clicar no botão PESQUISAR FORNECEDOR aparecerá essa View

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora preciso desenvolver uma caixa de texto que ao digitar um valor ele procure todos os FORNECEDORES que contenha um NOME FANTASIA igual ao digitado na caixa de texto.

Esse Controller mostra todos os fornecedores, mas só quero os com NOME FANTASIA digitado na caixa de texto:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SistemaDBEntities db = new SistemaDBEntities())
            {
                return View(db.Fornecedor.Where(s => s.Ativo == true).ToList());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: J.C. Galhard, você deseja que a cada vez que digitar na caixa de texto seja feita a pesquisa ou digitaria e depois pesquisaria?

Comment: Depois pesquisaria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu revolvi assim o meu problema:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Index(string sConsulta)
{
    var consulta = db.Fornecedor.Where(s => s.NomeFantasia.Contains(sConsulta)).ToList();
    return View(consulta);
}



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <p>Digite o nome/fantasia</p>
 <input placeholder="Digite o Nome/Fantasia" type="text" name="sConsulta" id="sConsulta"  />
 <div><button type="submit">Consultar</button></div>   
}
```